# Procedure to find component in new unit

Tags: delphi

I try to create new unit **Ado_Op** , in this `unit` i try to create a `procedure` like this :

```
procedure CloseAllTables ();
Var I : Integer;   T : TADOTable;
begin
for I := 1 to ComponentCount-1 do
  if Components[i] is TADOTable then
  begin
    T := FindComponent(Components[i].Name) as TADOTable;
    T.Close;
  end;
T.Destroy;
end;
```

**Error :**

> `ComponentCount` inaccessible.

**Note :** I'm using **Delphi 10 Seattle**.

Comment: Naturally. You have to supply an object.  Like someobj.ComponentCount. Also, you need to use zero based indexing.  And why would you use FindComponent if you already have the component? Why are so many delphi programmers obsessed with FindComponent?

Comment: If i have 12 `TAdoTable` in my form , i don't want to write `adotable.close` or `Adotable.Open` 1 2 time. So instead of 12 line , just one line :). that 'll be easy.

Comment: I can understand that. But you don't need FindComponent. And you do need to supply this procedure with the owner of the components you wish to iterate.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok , So how can i find All the tables and Close it or Open it if i don't use `FindComponent` ?

Comment: What do you think `Components[i]` is if not the component named `Components[i].Name`?

Comment: Ah,Yes you are right , i got it now, thank you so much @DavidHeffernan :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131908/discussion-between-sami-and-david-heffernan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler error you report is just the beginning of your problems. There are quite a few more. I see the following problems, with item 1 being the one noted in the question:

1. You need to supply an object on which to refer to the properties `ComponentCount` and `Components[]`.
2. You are erroneously using one based indexing.
3. You needlessly call `FindComponent` to find the component that you already have.
4. You call `Destroy` once only, on whichever object you found last. Or on an uninitialized variable if you don't find any. The compiler should warn of this, and I do hope you have warnings and hints enabled, and heed them.

Based on the comments you are trying to call the `Close` method on each table owned by a form. Do that like so:

```
procedure CloseAllTables(Owner: TComponent);
var 
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Owner.ComponentCount-1 do 
    if Owner.Components[i] is TADOTable then
      TADOTable(Owner.Components[i]).Close;
end;
```

If you wish to destroy all of these components too, which I doubt, then you would need to run the loop in descending order. That's because when you destroy an component, it is removed from its owners list of components. That code would look like this, assuming that there was no need to call `Close` on an object that is about to be destroyed.

```
procedure DestroyAllTables(Owner: TComponent);
var 
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Owner.ComponentCount-1 downto 0 do 
    if Owner.Components[i] is TADOTable then
      Owner.Components[i].Free;
end;
```

Comment: You should probably note that the user of a component should *never* call Destroy, but should always call *Free* instead, which handles checking for nil.

Comment: Destroy is fine here because of the is test. I just always use Free as a matter of course to avoid having to think about nil or not.

Comment: Yes, but someone who clearly is relatively new to coding (based on the code in the question) shouldn't be having to think about that stuff. Always calling Free is a much better habit to get into.